# Reproduction, Probability, and Independence

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A family has $n$ children. Assume that it is equally probable for a boy or a girl to be born. For which values of $n$ are the events "there are children of both sexes" an "there is at most one girl" independent?

---

Further, let $n=100$. Now randomly select $6$ from them knowing that exactly $10$ of them is wearing a blue shirt. What is the probability of obtaining at least one blue-shirted child?

Comment: Draw $\Omega$ for the first few $n$ and the respective subsets for your two events.

Comment: For anybody else reading this "$\Omega$" means the "universe."

Comment: "Draw $\Omega$" is possibly the most confusing two-word phrase I have encountered all day. I believe you mean something like "Write down all possible outcomes"?

Comment: The set of all possible outcomes is commonly referred to as $\Omega$, yes. Thus for $n=3$ we have $\Omega = \{BBB,BBG,BGG,GGG\}$

Comment: A familiy with 100 children? With 9 months per child, this gives for a single woman a minimum of 900 months, that is 75 years, of serial pregnancy. I conclude that it must be a bigamist family with at least three women ;-)

Comment: The title of this question can be read in a different manner; I voted for Rated-R.

Comment: @celtschk: bigamist family with three women... I've heard about both polygamy and same-sex marriages being legal someplace or somewhere else, but both at the same time is a first. Unless you're thinking of a cascading marriage with one guy married to two women one of whom is married to another guy, married to a third woman. This is getting a bit graph-theroetic for a combinatorial question. Then again, you can always adopt a child. Or ten. Or a hundred, maybe.

Comment: @tomasz: I of course meant a polygamist family. But then, why should a two-men-three-women family not be possible as well? :-) But I wonder about those tree women you speak about, are they maybe Ents? ;-)

Comment: You guys are forgetting twins, triplets, quadruplets and other multiple births, as well as premature births. Also, $m$-men-$w$-women type of relationship for $m,w \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m+w \ge 3$ exists. Check [polyamory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyamory). Btw, +1 for the question title.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the question is for the former part.

For the latter part:

It's typical to solve "at least one" questions by finding the "none" scenario then finding the complement. So first, the odds of having no blue shirts at all.

The chance of picking a single non-blue shirt is 90/100.

The chance of the next pick to not be a blue shirt is 89/99.

This continues until you've reached six children, so (90*89*88*87*86*85)/(100*99*98*97*96*95), which gives 448,282,533,600/858,277,728,000, or approximately 52.23% of no blue shirts.

Taking the complement, you get 409,995,194,400/858,277,728,800 of at least one blue shirt, or around 47.77%

Edit: Of course, the final answer can be reduced to 18,981,259/39,735,080.